# Mapbox GL JS - combining pop-up markers with geolocate

Tags: javascript, geolocation, javascript-objects, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to write a script that allows for pop-up markers while centering on the user's location - ultimately to be displayed as a webpage on a mobile phone.

I have successfully managed to enable the pop-up markers. I have also successfully managed to enable geolocation using both the Mapbox API `mapboxgl.GeolocateControl` and the HTML API `geolocate.GetCurrentPosition`. But when I add in the geolocate variable so that I have both geolocation AND pop-ups, the pop-ups stop working. When I take out geolocation, they start working again. Inverting the workflow has the same issue.

I suspect this has something to do with the hierarchy of different objects or variables, but I can't seem to be able to fix it, and haven't seen this issue anywhere on the usual forums.

Anyone got any thoughts or fixes? Or is there something super obvious that I'm missing?

I'd rather use the Mapbox script because the position marker is inbuilt. Code is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> My Map </title>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> My Map </title>

        <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
        <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.11.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
        <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.11.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <style>
             body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
             #map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
           .marker {
             background-image: url('mapbox-icon.png');
             background-size: cover;
             width: 50px;
             height: 50px;
             border-radius: 50%;
             cursor: pointer;
           }
           .mapboxgl-popup {
             max-width: 200px;
           }

           .mapboxgl-popup-content {
             text-align: center;
             font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
           }
          </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id='map'></div>
          <script>

            mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiY3dpbG1vdHQiLCJhIjoiY2s2bWRjb2tiMG1xMjNqcDZkbGNjcjVraiJ9.2nNOYL23A1cfZSE4hdC9ew'; //Put your own mapbox token

            var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
              container: 'map', // container id specified in the HTML
              style: 'mapbox://styles/cwilmott/ckbowmfzd3r761il84bnji13t' //change to your style
            });

            // Initialize the geolocate control.
            var geolocate = new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
              positionOptions: {
              enableHighAccuracy: true
            },
              trackUserLocation: true
            });

            // Add the control to the map.
            map.addControl(geolocate);
            map.on('load', function() {
            geolocate.trigger();
            });

            var geojson = {
              type: 'FeatureCollection',
                features: [{
      type: 'Feature',
      properties: {
        time: '2020-06-19T09:47:13Z',
        title: 'Point 1',
        description: '19 Jun 2020 at 10:47:13'
      },
      geometry: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [
          -2.219255366395865,
          53.457215089777584,

        ]
      }
    },
    {
      type: 'Feature',
      properties: {
        time: '2020-06-19T09:47:19Z',
        title: 'Point 2',
        description: '19 Jun 2020 at 10:47:19'
      },
      geometry: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [
          -2.219227672420135,
          53.457351307993434
        ]
      }
    }]
            }

            // add markers to map
  geojson.features.forEach(function(marker) {

    // create a HTML element for each feature
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.className = 'marker';

    // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
    new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
      .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
      .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
  .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 }) // add popups
    .setHTML('<h3>' + marker.properties.title + '</h3><p>' + marker.properties.description + '</p>'))
      .addTo(map);
  });

          </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I just tried to reproduce the issue uwing the code snippet mentioned in your question.
The geolocation was getting triggered as expected and pointed out my location correctly on the map and also the popup worked too.
Here is the link to it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mapbox-popup-geoloaction

The only change that I made was changed the marker style and attached a background color instead of a marker-icon.

Answer (score 0):

I also found another way of getting it to work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> My Map </title>
    <!--This where you put all your dependencies-->
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> My Map </title>
        <!--This where you put all your dependencies-->
        <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
        <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.11.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
        <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.11.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <style>
        /*this CSS section is where you style your page*/
        /*this is how you comment in CSS*/
             body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
             #map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
          </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <style>
          .mapboxgl-popup {
            max-width: 400px;
            font: 12px/20px 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
          }
        </style>
          <div id='map'></div>
          <script>

mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiY3dpbG1vdHQiLCJhIjoiY2s2bWRjb2tiMG1xMjNqcDZkbGNjcjVraiJ9.2nNOYL23A1cfZSE4hdC9ew';
  var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/cwilmott/ckbrpw01d29o31imqd2945ipn',
      center: [-122.259, 37.87], // starting position
      zoom: 15 // starting zoom
  });
// Initialize the geolocate control.
    var geolocate = new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
       positionOptions: {
           enableHighAccuracy: true
                     },
        trackUserLocation: true
                            });
// Add the control to the map.
  map.addControl(geolocate);

  map.on('load', function() {
    geolocate.trigger();
    map.addSource('places', {
          'type': 'geojson',
          'data': {
              'type': 'FeatureCollection',
              'features': [
                {
                                         'type': 'Feature',
                                         'properties': {
                                                'description': '<p>Example of a point.</p>',
                                                },
                                          'geometry': {
                                                'type': 'Point',
                                                'coordinates': [-2.219255, 53.457215]
                                                }
                                          },
                {
                                          'type': 'Feature',
                                          'properties': {
                                                'description': '<p>Example of a second point.</p>',
                                                },
                                          'geometry': {
                                                'type': 'Point',
                                                'coordinates': [-2.219371, 53.457349]
                                                }
                                          }

              ]
          }
      });
          // Add a layer showing the places.
      map.addLayer({
          'id': 'places',
          'type': 'symbol',
          'source': 'places',
          'layout': {
              'icon-image': 'marker-stroked-15',
              'icon-allow-overlap': true
          }
      });

      // When a click event occurs on a feature in the places layer, open a popup at the
      // location of the feature, with description HTML from its properties.
      map.on('click', 'places', function(e) {
          var coordinates = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates.slice();
          var description = e.features[0].properties.description;

          new mapboxgl.Popup()
              .setLngLat(coordinates)
              .setHTML(description)
              .addTo(map);
      });

  });
                </script>
              </body>
            </html>
```